# Is there a mini python interpreter

Tags: python

As I know there is a mini ruby interpreter
[MiniRuby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby)

Jsut wonder if there is a mini python interpreter with basic function&data type.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you are looking for... but there is [Embedded Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbeddedPython) and [Tiny Python](http://www.tinypy.org/).

Also you can use something like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) if that's what you are looking for.